# Swapping traits between two hashmaps

Tags: rust

I have two HashMaps and want to swap a value between them under certain conditions. If the key does not exist in the second HashMap, it should be inserted. I do not want to clone the value, since that is too expensive.

But in this example, I just want to take the `trait ATrait` out of the `HashMap` and move it to another `HashMap`

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Foo {
    type Bar;
}

struct Analyze<T: Foo> {
    save: T,
}

trait ATrait {}

impl<T: Foo> ATrait for Analyze<T> {}

struct SomeStruct;
impl Foo for SomeStruct {
    type Bar = ();
}

fn main() {
    let mut hm: HashMap<usize, Box<dyn ATrait>> = HashMap::new();
    let mut hm1: HashMap<usize, Box<dyn ATrait>> = HashMap::new();

    hm1.insert(
        1,
        Box::new(Analyze {
            save: SomeStruct {},
        }),
    );

    /*
    --------
    Swapping values between two HashMaps
    --------
    */
    let t1 = hm1.remove(&1);
    hm.insert(1, Box::new(t1));
}
```

And I got an error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<dyn ATrait>>: ATrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:37:18
   |
37 |     hm.insert(1, Box::new(t1));
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ATrait` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<dyn ATrait>>`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn ATrait`
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a064bbf187f28c1412c5413db8bd29e7)

I would appreciate if someone answered my question and explained to me what this error means.

Comment: I don't know what to explain fs is a option of a box of ATrait. just unwrap or similar `let fs = hm1.remove(&1).unwrap(); hm.insert(1, fs);`

Comment: @Stargateur Sorry, I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the value you get back from calling [`remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove) on a hashmap is `Option<V>` where `V` is the type of values stored in the map, which makes sense - otherwise what would it return if the value you were asking for was not present?

Second, the type stored in the `HashMap` is `Box<dyn ATrait>`, so no need to re-box it to store it in the second `HashMap`.

This would work:

```
let t1 = hm1.remove(&1).unwrap();
hm.insert(1, t1);
```

However, only use `unwrap` if you are completely certain that the value would be present and the program could not continue if it were not. Otherwise use a `match`, `if let`, etc to handle the logic appropriately.